# Why is jQuery firing my trigger twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got some simple jQuery to hide and show a menu. And when you click outside the menu, it's supposed to hide it. But if I click on the menu's trigger target (ex. a link), it hides then re-opens the menu, instead of just hiding it.

```
var notifyMenu = $(".notifyMenu .menu");

if (!notifyMenu.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
&& notifyMenu.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
{
    notifyMenu.hide();
    screenOverlay.hide();

}


$('.notifyMenu > a').click(function(event) {
    var menuID = $(this).parent().prop("id");
    var notifyMenu = $('#' + menuID + ' .menu');

    if (notifyMenu.is(':visible')) {
        screenOverlay.fadeOut();
        notifyMenu.fadeOut('fast');
    } else {
        // Show screenoverlay if on mobile
        if (ftrNav.is(':visible')) {
            screenOverlay.fadeIn('fast');
        }
        notifyMenu.fadeIn('fast');
    }

    event.preventDefault();

});
```

The HTML looks like this:

```
<li id="userLI" class="notifyMenu">
            <a href="/player/profile">
                &nbsp;
                <div class="profilePhoto">JM</div>
                <span class="fa fa-angle-down"></span> <div class="numVal"></div>
            </a>

            <div class="menu playerMenu" style="display: block;">
                <div class="upArrow"></div>
                <ul>
                    <li class="playerDetails">
                        <div class="name">Jon Marus</div>
                        <div class="access">
                            MANAGER (Spare)                     </div>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/player/profile/"><div class="icon fa fa-user-circle-o" title="Player Profile"></div> Profile</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/player/notifications"><div class="icon fa fa-bell"></div> Notifications</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/player/password"><div class="icon fa fa-lock"></div> Change Password</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/logout"><div class="icon fa fa-sign-out" title="Logout"></div> Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is how DOM events work. Each and every event will propagate to the document object.

So you need to add `event.stopPropagation()` to the menu onclick. Then document's onclick event handler will not be called when the menu is clicked.

Example:

```
$(document).on('click', function() {
  //Hide the menu etc...
  $('.notifyMenu .menu').hide();
}

$('.notifyMenu .menu').on('click', function(e) {
   //Show or toggle code goes here
   $('.notifyMenu .menu').show();
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I had tried that. I changed the onclick to: `code` if (!notifyMenu.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
&& notifyMenu.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
{
    notifyMenu.hide();
    screenOverlay.hide();

} `code`

Comment: Wow I am terrible at commenting.

Comment: I have added an example. This is a classic general purpose dropdown approach

Comment: This is a great example. Although this doesn't seem to work in my case. Something else is causing the (document).on('click') to fire twice.

Comment: Could you please replicate the problem in a jsfiddle or similar? Then we can work on it together

Comment: Sure! Here's a Gist: https://gist.github.com/jmarus/261560332795dc7f0abe3c52ab10f901

Comment: OK, I ran it but there is nothing much to go. I have created a fiddle for it: https://jsfiddle.net/mehmetb/pjm81n9a/ Feel free to fork/edit it. Fiddle would be much easier

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136996/discussion-between-jon-and-mehmet-baker).